# Android google map showing grey tiles, but only when its exported from eclipse

Tags: java, android

Any ideas why it works fine when I debug the code but when I export it, the grey tiles show up any ideas? Thanks in advance

My xml file looks like this i dont see anything wrong and ive used the code(not the xml)
Before and it worked fine i will try making a new keystore.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >






                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <WebView
                        android:id="@+id/webView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                        android:id="@+id/mvMain"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="830dp"
                        android:layout_weight="6.20"
                        android:apiKey="0e6eU8JA0MTaiN1Z-pYPpdEgK1-cu_oKcRRaPLg"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:enabled="true" >
                    </com.google.android.maps.MapView>

                </LinearLayout>





                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="234dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Set Login" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="234dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Check Current Stats" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:text=""/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You're using the wrong key to sign it?

Comment: it means map is not showing , am i right ?

Comment: you should post some code, so it will easy to get whats wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please go throgh this process :

```
      1. Create New Certificate.
      RightClick on Project > Android Tools> Export Signed Application Package.

       2. create new keystore. 
          C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias Fivecondition -keystore d:\Fivecondition

      3.Go to http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-api-signup.html
```

after this use this key and export apk with same certificate .

Comment: Ok so know it works when i export the app but when in debug it wont work, and on export it wont get my geoloaction but when its debugging it will any ideas?